# esp8266 advertising AP even when flashed with custom firmware

Tags: esp8266

I bought several ESP8266 boards from an Amazon seller, and I have flashed them with custom firmware.  This firmware basically sends telemetry to an MQTT server, and has some OTA functionality to self-update from a web server I run.

I flashed them from the Arduino IDE initially, although have also since updated them OTA.

These devices properly connect to the AP I have defined, get an address, and send their mqtt messages.  However, they ALSO advertise an SSID that is `FaryLink_XXXXXX` where the XXXXXX relates to the MAC.

How is this possible, and how should I wipe their little brains fully?

Comment: `WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);`

Comment: Ahh.  So obvious when you know what it is.  Of course, one wonders why it chooses that SSID when I can't find it in the source, or binary, anywhere...

Comment: please read the answer. setting `mode` only turns off the AP in setup(). it will start at boot

Answer (score 1):

The Espressif ESP8266 SDK is part of every Arduino sketch for the ESP8266. The SDK handles the WiFi and other basic functions of the chip.

If enabled, the SDK remembers WiFi STA and SoftAP settings and start to connect right after boot. At default it is enabled. In Arduino sketch this is controlled by [`WiFi.persistent(bool)`](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/generic-class.html#persistent) and of course this setting is stored too.

To clear SoftAP settings, call `WiFi.softAPdisconnect()`. To only turn off SoftAP, use `WiFi.setMode(WIFI_STA)`.